# Produce an array of strings from a single string

Tags: beginner, strings, delphi

I have a function that reads a string like this

```
(AnimalCount+HumanCount)
```

and the result of this function is an array of strings

```
[ "(" , "AnimalCount" , "+" , "HumanCount" , ")" ]
```

Now, I have done 2 functions in order to do this:

The first one to check if a given char is "special" from the input string

```
function Validate(Character: Char): Boolean;
begin
  Validate:= Character in [',' , '+' , '-' , '*' , '/' , '(' , ')' , '^' ,
                         '[' , ']' , '%' , '&' , '=' , '<' , '>' , ' ' ,
                         '.' , ';' , ':'];
end;
```

The second one to separate the strings from the input:

```
function GetToken(Chain:String):ArrayofString;
Var NTokens,i,j:Integer;
begin
  NTokens:=0;
  SetLength(Result,0);
  For i := 1 to Length(Chain) do
    if Validate(Chain[i]) then
      begin
        Inc(NTokens);
        setlength(Result,NTokens+1);
        Result[NTokens]:=Chain[i];
        Inc(NTokens);
      end
    else
      begin
        If Length(Result)<NTokens+1 then
          begin
            setlength(Result,NTokens+1);
            Result[NTokens]:='';
          end;
        Result[NTokens]:=Result[NTokens]+Chain[i];
      end;    
end;
```

Additionally, I had to put this after `type` to make it work this way:

```
Arrayofstring = array of String;
```

This functions are working, but I wonder if there is any way to improve it even further.  I am new to Delphi, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please can you specify in which ways you want this to be improved?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks for sending me here btw, well, i just wonder if the result i am getting could be achieved in fewer steps, like i said i am new to delphi and programming in general

Comment: I'd use TStringList or TStrings for the output. I'd always pass string args by const for perf reasons. I'd avoid building strings char by char and use a single Copy() to make new items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delphi is a nice language in that it is not case sensetive. However, I would still encourage you to stick to one casing. Decide on if you want to use `if` or `If` and stick to that. (My personal opinion: Use all lowercase). This also goes for `var` and `for` in your code.

---

Your code has a bit of inconsistent spacing. Take a look at this line for example:

```
Result[NTokens]:=Result[NTokens]+Chain[i];
```

I would write this as:

```
Result[NTokens] := Result[NTokens] + Chain[i];
```

I also think that you can use more spaces in your function header for `GetToken` (compare it with `Validate`). And also use a space after each comma (in parameter lists and variable declarations).

---

Your `Validate` method is quite good. I agree with ChrisWue that the naming could be better.

As for your GetToken method, that can be drastically improved.

Instead of appending char-by-char to the `Result[NTokens]` string, consider using a `var Current: String`, add the chars to that string and then when you encounter the next token separator you add the `Current` to the result.

Regarding your Result, instead of using an array of String, consider the class `TStrings` or `TStringList`.

Speaking of TStringList, that actually has support for using delimiters. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335027/delphi-stringlist-delimiter-is-always-a-space-character-even-if-delimiter-is-se) for an example.

If you want to do this yourself (which can be good practice), I would suggest returning a `TStringList` and calling the add method to add new strings to it. Here's a start for you on returning TStringList, as it's been a while since I used Delphi you will have to fix my mistakes and possibly change some stuff to make it work.

```
Result := TStringList.Create;
Current := "";
for i := 1 to Length(Chain) do
if IsTokenDelimiter(Chain[i]) then
begin
    if (Length(Current) > 0) then
        Result.Add(Current);
    Result.Add(Chain[i]);
    Current = "";
else
  begin
    Current = Current + Chain[i];
  end;
```

If you want to learn more about using built-in systems, take a look around at the TStringList class and see if it's delimiter system can simplify things for you. Perhaps it can't, in which case you might want to google for other Delphi classes that *can*. It's been a while since I've used Delphi, so I can't recommend a specific something that I know would work for you.

Lastly, I would like you to think about why you need this feature. Where does your string come from? If it's input from the user, then it's probably fine (although you might want to seperate the user inputs). If it is result from a function that you wrote, use a **record**, an **object** or a **class** type. Really, learn how to write your own records and objects and classes! They will simplify many things for you.

Comment: Returning a TStringList as a function result is considered bad practice because it could create a memory leak if an exception occurs within your function after you created that object. Using an array of string is better in this regard because it is reference counted.

Comment: @dummzeuch Good advice. It's been way too long since I used Delphi apparently :) Welcome to Code Review!

Answer (score 4):

1. `Validate` is a misleading name for what the function does. It does not validate anything - rather it checks if the given character is one of a special set. So it should be named `IsSpecial` or `IsTokenDelimiter`.
2. Growing an array one entry at a time is quite a bit of overhead. [There are some ways of mitigating this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755998/appending-one-element-to-a-dynamic-array).
3. Consider creating a local variable like `currentCharacter` in which `Chain[i]` - this would make it a little bit easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function for delimited string to TStringList conversion from my utilities library:

```
function  DelimitedStringToStringList
          ( const ADelimitedString: String;
            const ADelimiter      : Char ): TStringList;
var
  I               : NativeInt;
  SeparatedString : String;
begin

  SeparatedString := '';
  Result          := TStringList.Create;

  for I := 1 to Length ( ADelimitedString ) do
  begin

    if ADelimitedString [I] = ADelimiter then
    begin

      if SeparatedString <> '' then
      begin
        Result.Add ( SeparatedString );
        SeparatedString := '';
      end;

    end
    else
      SeparatedString := SeparatedString + ADelimitedString [I];

  end;

  if SeparatedString <> '' then
    Result.Add ( SeparatedString );

end;
```

You may derive your own solution from this.